# Receber Json via post Ajax PHP

Tags: php, ajax

Bom dia!

Tenho este código que envia um array contendo dados em formato json:

Array Json:

```
{"cliente":[{"Code":"1","Name":"A"},{"Code":"2","Name":"B"}]}
```

Ajax:

```
$('#btn-sinc').click(function(){

            $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: 'http://localhost/appread/Post.php',
                  data: "cliente="+ClienteStorage,
                  crossDomain: true,
                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                  dataType: 'jsonp',
                  success: function (responseData, textStatus, jqXHR){
                      console.log(responseData);
                  },
                  error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                  {
                      console.warn(responseData, textStatus, errorThrown);
                        alert('Falha no envio - ' + textStatus);
                  }
            });

        });
```

Este Ajax na pasta Projeto 1 e envia para PHP Projeto 2

PHP:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');

echo json_encode(array($_POST['cliente'], true));
```

Quando envio retorna esse erro:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token
    Post.php?callback=jQuery1520194…_1477050103032&cliente={"cliente":[{"Code":"1","Name":"…:1 


Object {readyState: 4, status: 200, statusText: "parsererror"}abort: (a)complete: ()done: ()error: ()fail: ()getAllResponseHeaders: ()getResponseHeader: (a)isRejected: ()isResolved: ()overrideMimeType: (a)promise: (a)readyState: 4setRequestHeader: (a,b)status: 200statusCode: (a)statusText: "parsererror"success: ()then: (a,c)__proto__: Object "parsererror" "jQuery15201942096755848719_1477050103032 was not called"
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia o que eu posso fazer?

Comment: Olá amigo, no ajax, no dataType, é "jsonp" mesmo? não "json"?

Comment: @GabrielSantos se eu colocar json ele retorna null também ele cai dentro do `error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown)`

Comment: E se você trocar esta linha: data: "cliente="+ClienteStorage,
Por essa: data: ClienteStorage,
O próprio JSON ja esta dizendo que o nome é cliente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente alterar seu Jquery do ajax para isso.

```
$('#btn-sinc').click(function(){

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://localhost/appread/Post.php',
        data: ClienteStorage, //***Esta Linha
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json', //***Esta Linha
        success: function (responseData, textStatus, jqXHR){
            console.log(responseData);
        },
        error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.warn(responseData, textStatus, errorThrown);
            alert('Falha no envio - ' + textStatus);
        }
    });

});
```